# Entity to support multiple dialects

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, orm

I have an SQLAlchemy entity written for PostgreSQL dialect and it uses `server_default=func.clock_timestamp()`:

```
row_created = sa.Column('row_created_', sa.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.clock_timestamp(), nullable=False)
```

I also need to use it with SQLite, which throws an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown function: clock_timestamp()

How do I make this work with SQLAlchemy? Define the `server_default` only for SQLite? Conditionally add entire column only for specific dialect? Somehow make `clock_timestamp()` known to SQLite (I don't care what the function will do, as long as it does not fail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tip from a colleague of mine, which I ended up using and it works fine for both postgresql as well as sqlite.

```
server_default=func.now()
```

afaik it is the same as func.clock_timestamp(), but clock_timestamp() is postgresql-specific and now() is supoported by several DBs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")` for the server default:

```py
class TimeStamp(Base):
    __tablename__ = "timestamp"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        primary_key=True,
    )

    datetime_with_tz: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        types.DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
    )
```

This will create a table with the following SQL:

PostgresSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timestamp (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        datetime_with_tz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

SQLite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timestamp (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        datetime_with_tz DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If you must use `clock_timestamp()` on PostgreSQL, you can set server default
to:

```py
server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") if use_sqlite else text("clock_timestamp()"),
```

postgres

```sql
CREATE TABLE timestamp (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        datetime_with_tz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT clock_timestamp() NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

sqlite

```sql
CREATE TABLE timestamp (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        datetime_with_tz DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

You can also use "default" for it to work on both databases.

```py
timestamp_auto = Annotated[
    datetime.datetime,
    mapped_column(
        default=datetime.datetime.now,
    ),
]


class TimeStamp(Base):
    __tablename__ = "timestamp"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        primary_key=True,
    )

    datetime_with_tz: Mapped[timestamp_auto] = mapped_column(
        types.DateTime(timezone=True),
    )
```